# I'm trying to generate a keystore file in command prompt but when i enter password it doesnt show

Tags: android, cordova, command-line, command-line-interface, android-keystore

I'm using adobe's build.phonegap to build an app for android. I'm using the command line to try and generate a keystore file for the app. I've used the following commands and been successful to the point where i am asked to enter a keystore password. however when i try to type a password, nothing i type comes up  in the command line. i am new to using the command so i could be missing something simple. help would be appreciated. thanks.

In the command line I typed:

```
cd C:\Program files
cd Java 
cd jdk1.8.0_51 
cd bin 

keytool -genkey -v -keystore Your_personal_file_title.keystore -alias Your_personal_alias -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 10000
```

[image: screenshot of command line prompting for password]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> when i try to type a password, nothing i type comes up in the command
>   line

Definitely, you'll not be able to see the password you type. This is due to security. But don't worry,  whatever you type is actually being treated as password after you hit Enter.

Comment: great thank you. i didn't realize that. It has worked now :)

Comment: Same with me. But i think it show some *, So we can recognize that password is being entered.